# Grab commandline of processes with Get-NetTCPConnection

Tags: powershell

I would like to see commandline of processes. I know I can grab cmd line of a process using:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId = '14376'").commandline
```

But I need to grab cmd line from a `Get-TCPNetConnection` command like so:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object OwningProcess,@{Name="cmdline";Expression={(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId = $_.OwningProcess").commandline}} | Format-Table | select -first 7
```

However, command line is missing/blank. There's got to be something wrong with my syntax here that I am unable to identify. Or is it because it is too long of a string that it doesn't show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the `$_.owningprocess` into a subexpression `$()`

```
Get-NetTCPConnection |
    Select-Object OwningProcess,
                 @{Name="cmdline";Expression={(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId = $($_.OwningProcess)").commandline}}
```

Only the base variable can expand in double quotes without subexpression

And if you really want the last 7 processes you need to swap your Select and Format commands. As written 2 of the lines will be part of the formatting so you'll end up with 5 processes.